# Android Database return wrong results

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio

I wanted to retrieve the id(primary key) of a particular row. The database only contains two column, which id and a string type of column.

```
ChordDatabase cdb;
int RowID = cdb.FindInDatabase(temp);
Log.i("RowID==>",String.valueOf(RowID));


public int FindInDatabase(String info){
    Log.i("String====>>>",info);
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseTable + " WHERE " + DataField + " = " + info,null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c.getInt(1);
}
```

above code will give me no error but give a wrong result, the result always return the first row. what is wrong over here? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had found the solution.

the return statement is wrong , it should be "return (c.getInt(0))"